# Is this a self-financing portfolio?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

I have $S_t = 10 + B_t$, $\beta_t = 1$, $a_t = 2B_t$, $b_t = -t - B_t^2 - 20B_t$

Then the value, $V = a_t S_t  + b_t \beta_t$

Is this a self financing portfolio? Note, $B_t$ is brownian motion

I am struggling to use Ito's lemma here to show if it is.

Essentially I just need to show

$dV = (2B_t)dSt + (b_t)d\beta_t$, correct?

but how can I do this?

Comment: @ Itosfriend : You have to check if the portfolio is self financing AND admissible. By the way this seems more suited for the QF StackExchange Forum. Best regards